# Bundling Multiple mySQL Counts

Tags: mysql, count

I have 7 states and 11 time spans from 09:00 to 20:00

I have a table:

```
id | name | time                | state
________________________________________
1  | aaaa | 2018-03-06 09:10:13 | NY
2  | bbbb | 2018-03-06 11:15:10 | LA
3  | cccc | 2018-03-06 13:02:11 | LA
4  | dddd | 2018-03-06 11:06:22 | NY
5  | eeee | 2018-03-06 09:33:17 | NY
6  | ffff | 2018-03-06 09:16:43 | LA
7  | gggg | 2018-03-06 17:08:36 | LA
8  | hhhh | 2018-03-06 14:25:47 | NY
9  | iiii | 2018-03-06 17:02:33 | LA
```

Here I have to repeat the same query for every possible state and hour from 09:00 to 20:00 (7 states x 11 time spans = 77 queries):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE state = "NY" AND time LIKE "% 09:%"
```

Now I want to get the number of records where:

- state = NY
- where time (HOUR) is the same

To get:

- 2x 09
- 1x 11
- 1x 14

And the same for LA in another query.

Is there w way to bundle the queries into 7 queries instead of 77 using `group by` or `join`?

I don't need any information from to be displayed, just the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the **group by state and time**

```
select group_concat(count(date_trunc('hour',time))," X ",date_trunc('hour',time)),state 
from table group by state, date_trunc('hour',time)
```

Comment: `date_trunc` is a PostgreSQL function not a MySQL function.. you can replace `date_trunc('hour',time)` with `HOUR(time)` or with `TIME_FORMAT(time, "%H")` in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code!

```
SELECT
state
, time_hour
, count(*)
FROM
(
SELECT
state 
, SUBSTR(time,12,2) AS time_hour
FROM your_table
) generate_time_hour
GROUP BY state, time_hour
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I correctly understood the question, but this is my solutions:

without concatenation

```
SELECT COUNT(*), HOUR(time) AS time, state
FROM `example`
GROUP BY state, HOUR(time)
```

with concatenation

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*), "x", TIME_FORMAT(time, "%H")) AS cnt, state
FROM `example`
GROUP BY state, HOUR(time)
```